# Webpack/Babel/React - "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, babeljs

I have a webpack-dev-server running that compiles and serves some Babel/React code. I have gotten as far as to have it serve the compiled `client.js` over `localhost:3001`.

But when I try to include the script in my HTML, I get the following error in Chrome's developer console:

```
routerWarning.js:19 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
```

That line belongs to react-router and contains the following code:

```js
process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production' ? _warning2['default'].apply(undefined, [falseToWarn, message].concat(args)) : undefined;
```

First, I don't see how that line of code would cause a syntax error. And second, I don't understand how it got in, because this looks like a piece of compiled (babelified) code to me. And finally, I don't know how to fix it! :(

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The line of code looks valid to me. There's not enough information to help properly.

Comment: After a good night's sleep I figured it out! Thanks anyway.

Comment: I tried, but it says to wait two days, so I'll wait :P

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was using webpack's DefinePlugin to set `process.env.BABEL_ENV` like this:

```js
new DefinePlugin({
  'process.env': {
    BABEL_ENV: JSON.stringify('client')
  }
});
```

This resulted in webpack replacing all instances of `process.env` in the code with `{"BABEL_ENV":"client"}`. The SyntaxError was caused in this part, not in the ternary expression.

I fixed it by setting `process.env.BABEL_ENV` like this:

```js
new DefinePlugin({
  'process.env.BABEL_ENV': JSON.stringify('client')
});
```