# Webpack Babel loading error - Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token import

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs

I'm new to Webpack and running into a problem following [this tutorial](http://jarstingstall.github.io/getting-started-with-webpack-part-3/).

It seems the webpack.config.js isn't setting up `babel-loader` correctly but I'm not sure.In the console I see the following error:

```
bundle.js:49 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
```

Which refers to the line `import sortBy from 'lodash/collection/sortBy';` of my `index.js`. So I assume it's a babel transpiling problem(not allowing the `import` syntax of ES6?)

Here is the complete `index.js` file

```
import sortBy from 'lodash/collection/sortBy';
import {users} from './users';
import {User} from './User';

sortBy(users, 'name')
    .map(user => {
        return new User(user.name, user.age);
    })
    .forEach(user => {
        console.log(user.display);
    });
```

And `webpack.config.js` looks like this:

```
module.exports = {
    entry: './src/index.js',
    output: {
        path: './public/',        
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    devServer: {
        contentBase: './public/'
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {test: /\.js$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: 'babel'}
        ]
    }
}
```

I've searched through other questions that looked like they relate to the problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33460420/babel-loader-jsx-syntaxerror-unexpected-token) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35965812/webpack-babel-react-uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-token) as well as googling around but haven't found a solution or reason why I'm getting the error yet. Maybe the tutorial is out of date.Any guidance how to fix this issue would be much appreciated!

**UPDATE**

The specific babel loading error was resolved by following the steps outlined in  answer posted below by Alexandre Thebaldi.

However, a new error occurred - 
`Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'lodash/collection/sortBy'`

If you are working through [this tutorial](http://jarstingstall.github.io/getting-started-with-webpack-part-one/) and encounter this error, it is most likely caused by an incorrect path in the `index.js`,specifically the fact that the `lodash/collections` directory seems to no longer exist. I managed to resolve this second error by simply changing the path to `lodash/sortBy`.

**NOTE**

Be sure to first check that `lodash` is installed in `node_modules` and the path is correct manually before changing it.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

First, make sure that you have installed babel core and loader by using:

`$ npm install --save-dev babel-loader babel-core`

So the correct loader is `babel-loader` and not `babel`. The config should be:

```
module: {
  loaders: [
    { test: /\.js$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: "babel-loader" }
  ]
}
```

---

Actually you need to tell babel to transform your code.

> Pre-6.x, Babel enabled certain transformations by default. However, Babel 6.x does not ship with any transformations enabled. You need to explicitly tell it what transformations to run. The simplest way to do this is by using a preset, such as the ES2015 Preset. You can install it with.

```
$ npm install babel-preset-es2015 --save-dev
```

After preset installed you have to enable it.

> Create a `.babelrc` config in your project root and enable some plugins.
>
> Assuming you have installed the ES2015 Preset, in order to enable it
>   you have to define it in your `.babelrc` file, like this:

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015"]
}
```

Details in [Babel Setup](https://babeljs.io/docs/setup/) page.

Comment: Great,thanks for the prompt help.Followed the instructions and got a new error `Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'lodash/collection/sortBy'`.I checked the lodash directory and found there isn't a `collection` sub-directory.So I changed the path to `lodash/sortBy' and then it worked.It's a shame the tutorial left out a big chunk of the babel configuration.

Comment: Thanks again for solving the core issue.I've accepted your answer and updated my question to include the fix for the separate issue `Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'lodash/collection/sortBy'`.Hopefully it will also help anyone getting that subsequent error while following the same tutorial.

Comment: my problem not solved *import { Config } from './util/config';
^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
*

Answer (score 2):

Mikeym

This is an issue with the babel-loader and ES6.

Can you change your webpack.config.js to this:

```
    module.exports = {
    entry: './src/index.js',
    output: {
        path: './public/',        
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    devServer: {
        contentBase: './public/'
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {test: /\.js$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: 'babel?presets[]=es2015' }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion.I managed to get it working and posted the steps in my answer above.Cheers!

Comment: my problem not solved * import { Config } from './util/config';
^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
*