# 'import' issue with React, webpack hot reload

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server, babeljs

I have an issue in my react project. I am using webpack dev server to serve my files. the webpack build is successful but I am getting an error on the browser like

> "app.js:7 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token import"

in the line:

```
import React from 'react';
```

Below is my webpack.config.js

```
module.exports = {
context: __dirname + "/app",    
entry: "./app.js",     output: {
    filename: "app.build.js",
    path: __dirname + "/dist",
},

module: {
    loaders: [
        {
            test: /\.jsx?$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            loaders: ["react-hot-loader", "babel-loader"],
        },
        {
            test: /\.html$/,
            loader: "file?name=[name].[ext]",
        },            

        { 
            test: /\.js$/, 
            exclude: /node_modules/, 
            loaders: ["react-hot-loader", "babel-loader"],
        }

    ]
}    
};
```

And in my `.babelrc` I have

```
{
   "presets": ["react", "es2015"]
}
```

I have tried adding various babel configs like using stage-0, stage-2, etc., but none of them worked. Is there any way to fix this.

Comment: does your `app.build.js` contain es6 syntax?

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38405514/webpack-babel-loading-error-uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-token-import

Comment: One thing for certain is that you don't need both the `.jsx?` and `.js` loaders. The first will match the file extension with or without an `x`.

Comment: @Jose, I don't see any es6 syntax in app.build.js. also I am referring to app.js in index.html(which I open in browser). app.build.js is what is generated after giving build, watch command from webpack. but for hot reloading via dev server app.js should be referred. please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @VipulSingh, I have already tried installing the npm libraries but nothing helped.

Comment: @Hacknightly, you are correct. but I think the issue lies somewhere else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found answer to my own question:

The way react hot loader works is the output file app.build.js mentioned in the webpack config.js is served by the hot loader server directly but not created under specific path(dist/) as mentioned in config.

so localhost/app.build.js is available instead of localhost/dist/app.build.js.

when I refer "script src="app.build.js" in my index.html it started working.

The file app.build.js is created in path ("/dist") only for "webpack" or "webpack --watch" command. not for "webpack-dev-server" command.