# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token import - Reactjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, webpack

My app was working perfectly fine just before i installed [simple-react-bootstrap](https://www.npmjs.com/package/simple-react-bootstrap)
After installing it is now showing blank page and in console it's showing error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token import

I have checked almost every solution on **stackoverflow** but it doesn't seems to work.

I have tried this:

```
npm install --save-dev babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-commonjs
```

This:

```
npm install babel-preset-es2015 babel-preset-react --save-dev
```

BABELRC file:

```
{
  "presets": ["react-app"]
}
```

And other similar solutions. Any help?

Comment: What is your .babelrc file?

Comment: please check edit.

Comment: Try using `["es2015", "react"]` in the presets. And let me know. if it worked

Comment: I have used `"presets": ["es2015", "react", "react-app"]` but no it's not working :(

Comment: Did you tried removing the `react` preset and then running too?

Comment: Yes Sir, same error. don't know what's wrong with `simple-react-bootstrap`

Comment: Why dont you try using http://react-bootstrap.github.io instead of `simple-react-bootstrap`

Comment: check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38405514/webpack-babel-loading-error-uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-token-import

Comment: I have tried that answer still not working. :( @ShivanshSingh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, i have resolved this by removing `react-simple-bootstrap` module from my app. That was making issue. Incase.